# SQL to generate a timestamp range until column value is not changed

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Motor is sending data every 10 seconds, I need to construct a timestamp range using SQL to figure out motor on and off status.

Sample data:

```
MOTOR_STATUS            TS                        MOTOR_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------
ON              2021-10-01 00:00:10                ABC
ON              2021-10-01 00:00:20                ABC
OFF             2021-10-01 00:00:30                ABC
OFF             2021-10-01 00:00:40                ABC
OFF             2021-10-01 00:00:50                ABC
ON              2021-10-01 00:01:00                ABC
ON              2021-10-01 00:00:10                ABD
OFF             2021-10-01 00:00:20                ABD
ON              2021-10-01 00:00:30                ABD
```

Expected Output:

```
MOTOR_STATUS      TS_FROM                  TS_TO                       MOTOR_NAME
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ON           2021-10-01 00:00:10      2021-10-01 00:00:30                ABC 
OFF          2021-10-01 00:00:30      2021-10-01 00:01:00                ABC 
ON           2021-10-01 00:01:00           NULL                          ABC               
ON           2021-10-01 00:00:10      2021-10-01 00:00:20                ABD
OFF          2021-10-01 00:00:20      2021-10-01 00:00:30                ABD
ON           2021-10-01 00:30:00           NULL                          ABD
```

Comment: "I need" is no question. What have you tried, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I have tried windowing function to partition data on columns, but wasn’t able to come up with correct approach.

Comment: Could you please edit the question, add the best query you wrote and explain what went wrong using this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select *, lead(ts_from) over(partition by motor_name order by ts_from) as ts_to
from (
  select motor_name, motor_status, min(ts) as ts_from,
  from (
    select *, 
      row_number() over(partition by motor_name order by ts) - 
      row_number() over(partition by motor_name, motor_status order by ts) as grp
    from your_table
  )
  group by motor_name, motor_status, grp
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MotorStatusTable AS (
    SELECT
        MOTOR_STATUS,
        TS AS TS_FROM,
        LEAD(TS) OVER (PARTITION BY MOTOR_NAME ORDER BY TS) AS TS_TO,
        MOTOR_NAME
    FROM
        <table_sample_Motor_data_is_stored>
)

SELECT
    MOTOR_STATUS,
    TS_FROM,
    TS_TO,
    MOTOR_NAME
FROM
    MotorStatusTable
WHERE
    MOTOR_STATUS = 'ON'
    OR TS_TO IS NULL
ORDER BY
    MOTOR_NAME,
    TS_FROM;
```

You will need to create a table containing data sent by motor if not already exists.

Comment: this wont work, you are not considering machine off status, need to find range when motor was on and turned off.

Comment: What do you mean by "you will need to create a table"? Why do they need so? Which columns should this table have and what data should be stored there?